# Как работать с json вложенным в другой json?

Tags: javascript, json

**Задание**

Имеется код:

```
{
    "html_attributions" : [],
    "results" : 
    [
        {
            "geometry" : 
            {
                "location" : 
                {
                    "lat" : 46.471497,
                    "lng" : 30.750842
                }
            },
            "icon" : "???",
            "id" : "???",
            "name" : "???",
            "place_id" : "ChIJkzSdrXAxxkARWx48TYl110Q",
            "reference" : "???",
            "scope" : "GOOGLE",
            "types" : [ "cafe", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
            "vicinity" : "???"
        }
    ],
    "status" : "OK"
}
```

**Вопрос**

Нужен класс который может распарсить все Json, чтоб не ручками парсить каждый по отдельности, а все разом.

Comment: Можно пример такой конструкции?

Comment: Мне не корректно объяснили ТЗ, сейчас переделаю...

Comment: что значит распарсить все JSON? что вы понимаете под JSON?

Comment: в коде у нас 3 объекта Json, один пустой, второй с массивом, третий со статусом *ОК*

Comment: создайте такой же java класс у которого будет три поля. Первое это коллекция "html_attributions" второе коллекция объектов "results" и третье поле это "status"

Comment: json вложенным в другой json думаю неверно сказано. json - это просто формат { } значит что это объект, а [ ] что это массив

Comment: как я и говорил можете создать объект с такими же полями и при запросе все прекрасно будет парситься, ну или можно получать данные по определенному ключу

Comment: это ясно, но вопрос в том есть ли какой-то класс который автоматизирует этот процесс?

Comment: для многих языков есть даже онлайн версии генераторов классов(вставил json получил классы языка программирования со всеми зависимостями) Пример: json2csharp. Забейте в гугле библиотек куча под java,c# и т.п.

Comment: как раз штудирую гугл.

Comment: прошу прощения, вам для какого языка надо?

Comment: Javascript, ищу в гугле, но в основном находятся элементарные примеры по работе с json.

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: очень интересно, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понимаю Вы о поле "results"
Наверное Вы имеете ввиду массив (список) Объектов.
Т.е. 
Разница
Между `"types" : [ "cafe", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ]`
И `"types" : [ {"f1":"cafe"}, {"f1": "food", "point_of_interest"}, {"f3": ["establishment"]} ]`

Особой нет.

В тэгах написано javascript и java
Если javascript, то Вам сюда:
https://learn.javascript.ru/json

Если java, то Вам сюда (например)
https://habrahabr.ru/company/naumen/blog/228279/